# Driving a 4 digit 7 segment common cathode from GPIO

Tags: rpi.gpio

I have 8 330 ohm resistors wired up to 8 gpio pins (8 anodes), then I have the 4 cathodes wired to 4 other gpio pins. I tested all my connections with a multimeter and everything looks good. Then when I run my python script, only some of the segments light up.

```python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

segments = {19, #a
            20, #b
            21, #c
            22, #d
            18, #e
            24, #f
            27, #g
            26} #dp

for segment in segments:
        GPIO.setup(segment, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(segment, 1) # send a signal to each segment

digits = [17, 16, 13, 12]

for digit in digits:
        GPIO.setup(digit, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(digit, 0)   # set the common cathode for each digit

try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Does it work with 1 digit, 2 digits, 3 digits?

Comment: 3 segments on 3 digits light up, particularly the 3 horizontal lights (although my mapping is off, the first step was to get all segments to light before I rearranged the pins to the proper segment). This script is just supposed to make all segments light on all digits, so the mapping isn't particularly relevant yet.

Comment: Does it work with 1 digit?

Comment: I changed the digits array to only use one just now, and it's lighting up 3 segments on 3 displays.

Comment: I'm trying to establish if it's a lack of power problem.  Have you set all the cathodes of the unused digits high?

Comment: Also, I tried reversing the polarity, just in case, it's definitely common cathode. I got it from Sparkfun - COM-11408 https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11408 if you're curious.

Comment: I just set GPIO 17, 16 and 12 to high and left the first segment to low, same strange behavior, just slightly different segments lit this time.

Comment: I tried adding some time in between, and it's lighting more segments. I'll try and up the resistors to something like 510 and try it again, you're probably right about the power draw.

Comment: Just curious: any reason to rollback the copy editing?

Comment: There was no visible change in the formatting, basically it looked the same before as it did after.

Comment: I added *<!-- language: lang-python -->* to enable syntax highlighting, see: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/630/should-we-have-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Ah I didn't see that. My mistake

Answer (score 2):

Add even more delay in between. I prefer to add about 5ms delay for every step in my loop. If the display is updated too fast, the segments will be utterly dim to the point where we can't see it.

Pseudocode:

```
while true:
    set the proper segment pins high
    if digit pin is 4, go back to first digit pin.
    set the proper digit pin low
    wait 5 milliseconds
    move to the next digit
```

Also, you're using common cathode (I'm sure you know). The cathode pins need to be driven low and the segment pins high. Also, lower your resistor value a bit. GPIO pins are 3.3v, not 5v.

One last note: make sure you're actually driving the correct segment. Diagram below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code I had forgotten about.  It should do what you intend.  It was intended as an example of using (my) pigpio waveforms to set GPIO levels.  If nothing else the character set may be useful.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# _7_segment.py
# 2015-08-07
# Public Domain

import time
import pigpio # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

# For testing purposes each LCD is refreshed (REFRESH) for
# 100000 microseconds.  In a practical application you probably
# want to use a figure in the region of 1000 microseconds.

REFRESH=100000

CHARSET={
' ': 0b00000000,
'0': 0b11111100,
'1': 0b01100000,
'2': 0b11011010,
'3': 0b11110010,
'4': 0b01100110,
'5': 0b10110110,
'6': 0b00111110,
'7': 0b11100000,
'8': 0b11111110,
'9': 0b11100110,
'A': 0b11101110,
'b': 0b00111110,
'C': 0b10011100,
'c': 0b00011010,
'd': 0b01111010,
'E': 0b10011110,
'F': 0b10001110,
'H': 0b01101110,
'h': 0b00101110,
'L': 0b00011100,
'l': 0b01100000,
'O': 0b11111100,
'o': 0b00111010,
'P': 0b11001110,
'S': 0b10110110,
}

# This defines which gpios are connected to which segments
#          a   b   c   d   e   f   g  dp
SEG2GPIO=[ 4, 17, 18, 22, 23, 10, 24,  9]

# This defines the gpio used to switch on a LCD
#          1   2   3   4   5
LCD2GPIO=[ 5,  6,  7,  8, 11]

wid = None

showing = [0]*len(LCD2GPIO)

CHARS=len(CHARSET)

def display(lcd, char):
   if char in CHARSET:
      showing[lcd] = CHARSET[char]
   else:
      showing[lcd] = 0

def update_display():
   global wid
   wf = []
   for lcd in range(len(LCD2GPIO)):

      segments = showing[lcd] # segments on for current LCD

      on = 0 # gpios to switch on
      off = 0 # gpios to switch off

      # set this LCD on, others off
      for L in range(len(LCD2GPIO)):
         if L == lcd:
            on |= 1<<LCD2GPIO[L] # switch LCD on
         else:
            off |= 1<<LCD2GPIO[L] # switch LCD off

      # set used segments on, unused segments off
      for b in range(8):
         if segments & 1<<(7-b):
            on |= 1<<SEG2GPIO[b] # switch segment on
         else:
            off |= 1<<SEG2GPIO[b] # switch segment off

      wf.append(pigpio.pulse(on, off, REFRESH))

      print(on, off, REFRESH) # debugging only

   pi.wave_add_generic(wf) # add pulses to waveform
   new_wid = pi.wave_create() # commit waveform
   pi.wave_send_repeat(new_wid) # transmit waveform repeatedly

   if wid is not None:
      pi.wave_delete(wid) # delete no longer used waveform

   print("wid", wid, "new_wid", new_wid)

   wid = new_wid

pi = pigpio.pi()

# Set all used gpios as outputs.

for segment in SEG2GPIO:
   pi.set_mode(segment, pigpio.OUTPUT)

for lcd in LCD2GPIO:
   pi.set_mode(lcd, pigpio.OUTPUT)

char=0

ck = CHARSET.keys()

while True:

   # To test loop over character set.

   for d in range(len(LCD2GPIO)):
      display(d, ck[(d+char)%CHARS])

   update_display()

   char += 1

   time.sleep(2)

pi.wave_delete(wid)

pi.stop()
```